# Constraint index field must be a JSON primitive

Tags: flutter, dart, firebase-realtime-database

I am using Flutter, Dart and Firebase Realtime Database.

I have the following URL which is supposed to fetch products based on selected category.

```
var filterString = filterByCategory ? 'orderBy="categoryName"&equalTo="$title"' : ''; 
  
var url = 'https://cc-9006.firebaseio.com/products.json?auth=$authToken&$filterString';
```

Let's say for instance my categoryName = 'Burgers & Wraps'. Hence, my filterString will look like this:

```
orderBy="categoryName"&equalTo="Burgers & Wraps"
```

Here's a snapshot of my DB.
[image]

Notice that the category says "Grilled Chicken", which means that I don't have any product under the category "Burgers & Wraps". When I click on "Burgers & Wraps" category in my app, I get the below error. What's this error indicate?

> Fetched products{error: Constraint index field must be a JSON
> primitive}

Here's my firebase Rules:

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "auth != null",  // 2020-11-5
    ".write": "auth != null",  // 2020-11-5
     "products": {
      ".indexOn": ["categoryName"]
    }
  }
}
```

What's the cause of this?

**Further Analysis:**

I have noticed that when I replace the letter ***&*** with ***and*** (i.e Burgers and Wraps) then the error disappears.  These category names are written by the end user. Hence, I do not want to restrict the end user to avoid using certain special characters like ***&*** . Hence, how do I take care of it in my dart code?

Comment: Take a look at https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data. Have you added to your Firebase rules?

Comment: Please see my updated question. I already have the index on categoryName